# R Shiny brush with facet_grid doesn't select correct points

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, brush, facet-grid

Please run the reproducible code here first.

Here are two box plots created. The upper one is simple. The bottom one is a box plot with `facet_grid`.

The idea is to link them together. Brushing points in one of them will highlight the points and the ones in the other box plot.

Now, selecting points in one box plot seems not to be functioning well.

And the box plot with `facet_grid` even doesn't work with itself.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


server <- function(input, session, output) {

  mtcars$cyl = as.character(mtcars$cyl)
  mtcars$gear = as.character(mtcars$gear)

  vals <- reactiveValues( keeprows = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$brush_1,{
    Res=brushedPoints(mtcars,input$brush_1,allRows = TRUE)
    vals$keeprows = Res$selected_
  })
  observeEvent(input$brush_2,{
    Res=brushedPoints(mtcars,input$brush_2,allRows = TRUE)
    vals$keeprows = Res$selected_
  })


  output$table1 = renderPrint({
    brushedPoints(mtcars,input$brush_1,allRows = TRUE)
  })

  output$table2 = renderPrint({
    brushedPoints(mtcars,input$brush_2,allRows = TRUE)
  })

  output$plot_1 = renderPlot({
    set.seed(123)
    ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=cyl,y=mpg)) + 
      geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
      geom_jitter(aes(color=vals$keeprows),width=0.2)+
      scale_color_manual(values = c("black","red"),guide=FALSE)    
  })
  output$plot_2 = renderPlot({
    set.seed(123)
    ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=cyl,y=mpg)) + 

      facet_grid(.~gear)+

      geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
      geom_jitter(aes(color=vals$keeprows),width=0.2)+
      scale_color_manual(values = c("black","red"),guide=FALSE)

  })


}

ui <- fluidPage(

  plotOutput("plot_1",brush = brushOpts("brush_1",resetOnNew = FALSE)),
  plotOutput("plot_2",brush = brushOpts("brush_2",resetOnNew = FALSE)),
  splitLayout(verbatimTextOutput("table1"),verbatimTextOutput("table2"))

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I believe the key issue lies in the `facet_grid` function.

How can we make `facet_grid` work fine with `brush`.

Thanks.

Comment: You could also do this client-side with plotly and [crosstalk](https://github.com/rstudio/crosstalk).